# How to generate different random numbers in one single runtime?

Tags: c, random, srand

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main ()
{
  int ctr;
  for(ctr=0;ctr<=10;ctr++)
    {
      int iSecret;
      srand ( time(NULL) );
      printf("%d\n",iSecret = rand() % 1000 + 1);
    }
}
```

And it outputs this:
256
256
256
256
256
256
256
256
256
256

Unfortunately, I want the output to print 10 different random numbers in that loop.

Comment: Referring to those that would help you as "geniuses" is likely to be considered rude. I recommend you edit your post.

Comment: why do you keep *srand*ing it?

Answer (score 6):

Move the call to `srand(time(NULL));` to before the `for` loop.

The problem is that `time()` changes only once in every second, but you're generating 10 numbers, and unless you have an *extremely* slow CPU, it won't take a second to generate those 10 random numbers.

So you're re-seeding the generator with the same value each time, making it return the same number.

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks for the edit. (It makes me feel I should improve my English skills... :( )

Comment: Fogadok, hogy az angol is jobb, mint a magyar: I bet your English is better than my Hungarian :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo As currently standing, that sentence means "I bet English is better than Hungarian, too" ;-) "Fogadok, hogy te jobban beszélsz angolul, mint én magyraul."

Comment: Hence proof positive that I was right about our relative language skills, or that Google Translate is mostly marhaság :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Google translate is actually quite good at translating to languages of which the grammar is consistent enough. Hungarian isn't one of them ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Put `srand ( time(NULL) );` before the loop. Your loop probably runs within a second so you are reinitialising the seed with the same value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main ()
{
  int ctr;
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  for(ctr=0;ctr<=10;ctr++)
    {
      int iSecret;
      printf("%d\n",iSecret = rand() % 1000 + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keep srand(time(0)) outside of the for loop.
it should not be inside that loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main ()
{
  int ctr;
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  for(ctr=0;ctr<=10;ctr++)
    {
      int iSecret;
      printf("%d\n",iSecret = rand() % 1000 + 1);
    }
}
```